# Find LAN Connection behind VPN using signed java applet?

Tags: java, windows, applet, vpn

I am able to run ipconfig /all on the client machine using signed java applet, how to find LAN Connection ip which initiated VPN Connection on client machine as there can be multiple LAN,WI-FI, Virtual connections ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such things with the standard Java API. You will have to connect to native code (either the command line or some C/C++ library using JNI) from your Java code.